# behavior of the sshfs user permissions

Tags: permissions, sshfs

I want to use one drive of the remote server in my current Linux system. So I have found out SSHFS is an option for that..
Using sshfs I am able to map the remote system drive as mount point in current Linux like below .

```
sshfs  -d -o debug,sshfs_debug,allow_other,nomap=ignore,idmap=file,uidfile=uidfile.uidmap,gidfile=gidfile.gidmap   root@XX.XX.XX.XX:/data/shared /data/sharedlocal/
```

content of the GID/UID file.

```
uidfile.uidmap
raj:502
rahul:503

gidfile.gidmap
prod:1023
```

After this i can see the mount points , but when i create any file inside the mount point , its user is always root .
I mean whatever i pass in this part [ root@XX.XX.XX.XX:/data/shared  ] . If i use raj , all files created with raj as user. How can i have each user to create there own file in the like below:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 raj prod 5 2017-07-02 20:01 rajfile
-rw-r--r-- 1 rahul prod 2 2017-07-02 20:01 rahulfile
```

Comment: The files on the server are created with the owner who is connecting to the remote server (in your case `root`). If you want to create the files with different owner, connect to the server using different user. There is no simple way around that.

Comment: @Jakuje..OK i got the point..but with allow_other anybody can see and go to mount and delete file...how about two users ...is there any way to limit it to only limited set of users...

Comment: There is a group permission that can be set to files and directories in Linux.